# Sending large files over socket in c

Tags: c, linux

So this code works ok for small files of up to 20KB but when i try to send or receive larger files it stops reading at some point. Two functions for client and server, to send and receive files. I know it might have some leaks and stuff but I will fix that later. At first I want it to work properly. BUF_SIZE=512

```
// SENDING BYTES
void send_bytes(int connfd, int client_number, char **command_parts)
{
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen(command_parts[1], "r");
    int i = 0;
    // FINDING BYTE SIZE OF THE FILE
    fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END); /* PUTTING FILE POINTER TO THE END OF THE FILE */
    int num_of_bytes = ftell(fp);
    fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET); /* RESETTING FILE POINTER TO THE BEGINNING OF THE FILE */
    char *sendbuff = malloc(num_of_bytes * sizeof(char));
    memset(sendbuff, '\0', num_of_bytes);
    // SENDING TOTAL BYTES TO SEND
    while (write(connfd, itoa(num_of_bytes), 10) < 0)
    {
    }
    printf("\nClient #%d --> Size of file sent: %d\n", client_number, num_of_bytes);

    // IF BYTES MORE THAN 512 SENDING IT IN PARTS
    if(num_of_bytes > BUF_SIZE)
    {
        int bytes_left_to_send = num_of_bytes;
        char *tempbuff = calloc(BUF_SIZE, sizeof(char));
        while(bytes_left_to_send > 0)
        {
            if(bytes_left_to_send >= BUF_SIZE)
            {
                // READING 512 BYTES AND PASSING IT TO TEMPBUFF
                for (i = 0; i < BUF_SIZE; i++)
                {
                    fread(&tempbuff[i], 1, 1, fp);
                }
                // SENDING BYTES
                while (write(connfd, tempbuff, BUF_SIZE) < 0)
                {
                }
                bytes_left_to_send = bytes_left_to_send - BUF_SIZE;
                memset(tempbuff, '\0', BUF_SIZE);
            }
            else
            {
                // READING 512 BYTES AND PASSING IT TO TEMPBUFF
                for (i = 0; i < bytes_left_to_send; i++)
                {
                    fread(&tempbuff[i], 1, 1, fp);
                }
                // SENDING BYTES
                while (write(connfd, tempbuff, bytes_left_to_send) < 0)
                {
                }
                bytes_left_to_send = bytes_left_to_send - bytes_left_to_send;
                memset(tempbuff, '\0', BUF_SIZE);
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // READING EACH BYTE AND PASSING IT TO SENDBUFF
        for (i = 0; i < num_of_bytes; i++)
        {
            fread(&sendbuff[i], 1, 1, fp);
        }
        // SENDING BYTES
        while (write(connfd, sendbuff, num_of_bytes) < 0)
        {
        }
    }

    // FREEING MEMORY
    fclose(fp);
    free(sendbuff);
    printf("\nClient #%d --> File sent\n", client_number);
}
// RECEIVING BYTES
void recv_bytes(int connfd, int client_number, char **command_parts)
{
    int bytes_read = 0, bytes_read_in_total = 0, i = 0;
    char *num_of_bytes = malloc(10 * sizeof(char));
    char *recvbuff = NULL;
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen(command_parts[2], "w");
    // RECEIVING BYTES TO RECEIVE
    while (read(connfd, num_of_bytes, 10) < 0)
    {
    }
    printf("\nClient #%d --> Size of file received: %d\n", client_number, atoi(num_of_bytes));
    recvbuff = malloc(atoi(num_of_bytes) * sizeof(char)); /* ALLOCATING recvbuff WITH RECEIVED SIZE */
    memset(recvbuff, '\0', atoi(num_of_bytes));

    // IF BYTES MORE THAN 512 RECEIVING IT IN PARTS
    if(atoi(num_of_bytes) > BUF_SIZE)
    {
        int bytes_left_to_read = atoi(num_of_bytes);
        char *tempbuff = calloc(BUF_SIZE, sizeof(char));
        while(bytes_left_to_read > 0)
        {
            if(bytes_left_to_read >= BUF_SIZE)
            {
                // READING BYTES
                while (bytes_read = read(connfd, tempbuff, BUF_SIZE) < 0)
                {
                }
                bytes_read = strlen(tempbuff);
                // WRITING BYTES READ SO FAR TO THE FILE
                for (i = 0; i < bytes_read; i++)
                {
                    fwrite(&tempbuff[i], 1, 1, fp);
                }
                bytes_left_to_read = bytes_left_to_read - bytes_read;
                memset(tempbuff, '\0', BUF_SIZE);
            }
            else
            {
                // READING BYTES
                while (bytes_read = read(connfd, tempbuff, bytes_left_to_read) < 0)
                {
                }
                bytes_read = strlen(tempbuff);
                // WRITING BYTES READ SO FAR TO THE FILE
                for (i = 0; i < bytes_read; i++)
                {
                    fwrite(&tempbuff[i], 1, 1, fp);
                }
                bytes_left_to_read = bytes_left_to_read - bytes_read;
                memset(tempbuff, '\0', BUF_SIZE);
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // RECEIVING BYTES
        while (bytes_read_in_total < atoi(num_of_bytes))
        {
            while (bytes_read = read(connfd, recvbuff, atoi(num_of_bytes)) < 0)
            {
            }
            bytes_read = strlen(recvbuff);
            bytes_read_in_total = bytes_read_in_total + bytes_read;

            // WRITING BYTES READ SO FAR TO THE FILE
            for (i = 0; i < bytes_read; i++)
            {
                fwrite(&recvbuff[i], 1, 1, fp);
            }
            memset(recvbuff, '\0', atoi(num_of_bytes));
        }
    }

    free(recvbuff);
    fclose(fp);
    printf("\nClient #%d --> File received\n", client_number);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and edit your question to include the exact error you're getting. E.g. Do you get the first part of the file or do large files completely fail? Have you determined an exact cut-off? etc. Can your code be reduced and still reproduce the error?