# linux TCP multiclient echo server in c

Tags: c, linux, sockets, tcp

I am currently studying TCP multiclient echo server and client using fork, thread, multiplexing IO and so on.
Below are the simple server and client using fork().

server_fork.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <signal.h>

#include <arpa/inet.h>

static const int BUFSIZE = 1024;

int readn(int fd, char *buf, short n);

int main(void)
{
  int cnt = 0;
  int listenFD, connectFD;
  struct sockaddr_in listenSocket, connectSocket;
  char buffer [BUFSIZE];

  if ((listenFD = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0) {
    perror("socket() error\n");
    exit(0);
  }

  if (setsockopt(listenFD, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &(int){ 1 }, sizeof(int)) < 0) {
    perror("sockopt error\n");
    exit(0);
  }

  memset(&listenSocket, 0, sizeof(listenSocket));
  listenSocket.sin_family = AF_INET;
  listenSocket.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("0.0.0.0");
  listenSocket.sin_port = htons(7777);

  if (bind(listenFD, (struct sockaddr *)&listenSocket, sizeof(listenSocket)) < 0) {
    perror("bind() error\n");
    exit(0);
  }

  if (listen(listenFD, 1) < 0) {
    perror("listen() error\n");
    exit(0);
  }

  signal(SIGCHLD, SIG_IGN);

  int connectSocketLen;
  short readLen;
  pid_t pid;

  while (1) {
    connectSocketLen = sizeof(connectSocket);
    if ((connectFD = accept(listenFD, (struct sockaddr *)&connectSocket,
            &connectSocketLen)) < 0) {
      perror("accept() error\n");
      exit(0);
    }

    pid = fork();
    cnt++;
    if (pid == 0) {
      close(listenFD);

      while (1) {
        memset(buffer, 0, BUFSIZE);
        if (readn(connectFD, buffer, 2) == 0) {
          break;
        }
        readLen = (*(short *)&buffer);
        if(readLen != 12)
          printf("[%d] : %d\n", cnt, readLen);
        if (readn(connectFD, buffer, readLen) == 0) {
          break;
        }
        buffer[readLen] = 0;
        int n;
        if ((n = write(connectFD, buffer, readLen)) <= 0) {
          perror("!!");
        }
        sleep(0);
      }
      close(connectFD);
      exit(0);
    }

    else if (pid > 0) {
      close(connectFD);
    }

    else {
      perror("fork() error\n");
      exit(0);
    }
  }
  close(listenFD);

  return 0;
}

int readn(int fd, char *buf, short n)
{
  short sp = 0, readed;
  while (n) {
    readed = read(fd, buf + sp, n);
    if (readed <= 0) {
      return 0;
    }
    n -= readed;
    sp += readed;
  }
  return 1;
}
```

client.c

```
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

static const int bufSize = 1024;

int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
  signal(SIGCHLD, SIG_IGN);
  fork();
  fork();
  fork();
  fork();
  fork();
  fork();
  fork();
  fork();
  //fork();
  //fork();

  char length[2], recvBuf[bufSize];
  char buf[]="hello, world\0";
  short len = strlen(buf);
  sprintf(length,"%c",len);
  int client_sockfd, size, i, n, state;

  uint64_t delta_us = 0;

  struct sockaddr_in server_addr;
  struct timespec start, end;

  client_sockfd = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
  memset(&server_addr, 0, sizeof server_addr);
  server_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
  server_addr.sin_port = htons(7777);

  inet_pton(AF_INET, "127.0.0.1", &server_addr.sin_addr.s_addr);

  state = connect(client_sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&server_addr, 
      sizeof server_addr);

  if (state < 0) {
    perror("connect err");
    exit(1);
  }

  for (i=0;i<10;i++) {
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC_RAW, &start);

    n = write(client_sockfd, length, sizeof length);
    if (n<=0) {
      perror("write err");
      exit(1);
    }
    n = write(client_sockfd, buf, *((short *)&length));
    if (n<=0) {
      perror("write err");
      exit(1);
    }

    n = read(client_sockfd, recvBuf, *((short *)&length));
    if (n<=0) {
      perror("read err");
      exit(1);
    }

    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC_RAW, &end);

    delta_us += (end.tv_sec - start.tv_sec) * 1000000 +
      (end.tv_nsec - start.tv_nsec)/1000;
    printf("%lu\n", delta_us);
    sleep(1);

  }
  return 0;
}
```

1. The client first transmits the length of the message represented by 2 bytes.
2. Then client sends a "hello, world" message to the server in buf.
3. The server first reads 2 bytes through readn () and reads the message as much.

But in all cases (fork, thread, multiplexing IO... whatever), I have a common difficulty.

The problem is that : In the above source code, the length of the message("hello, world" is 12. so it is expected to read 12 in the first readn () of the server.

In fact, when the number of clients is small (the number of forks on the client is 7 or less), it works fine.
However, if the number of clients increases, the value of readLen will be 25960 on some connections. 25960 is the value that represents "he" in hex.

Why is this problem happening when there are many clients?
I wonder if it is the same as sending a TCP packet at one time and dividing it two times.

Below is a tcpdump capture of the above problem situation.

I'm sorry that I could not upload the image right away.

[tcpdump](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bbtAr.png)

Comment: Why is the client sending `length` not `len`?

Comment: In fact, what's up with the client's use of `length` at all?  That doesn't make much sense, and it does not correspond to the method by which the server interprets the length sent.  Frankly, I have trouble believing that your system works as intended for *any* number of clients.

Comment: The client should use `readn()` as well.

Comment: Also replace this `..., *((short *)&length)` by just `length[0]`, at least as long as you do not send a string longer then 255.

Comment: Linux or many Unix systems, don't send everything which you tell them to send. they buffer it, there's a way to force them to send all the data and to receive all of it. See the answer I gave here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47066539/sending-large-files-over-socket-in-c/47067181#47067181

Comment: @ChrisTurner That would be a better way. Thank you

Comment: @alk Yes, client should also use readn(). But, the problem does not come from that point :(

Answer (score 2):

On the client side, you have multiple problems surrounding how you send the message length.  Starting here:

> ```
>   char length[2], recvBuf[bufSize];
>   char buf[]="hello, world\0";
>   short len = strlen(buf);
>   sprintf(length,"%c",len);
> ```

Your `sprintf` format promises that the third argument will be of type `char` (promoted to int), and instructs it to output the corresponding *character* into the string.  In fact, the argument is a `short` (promoted to `int`), and this mismatch produces undefined behavior.

In practice, the overall `sprintf` call is probably equivalent to this:

```
length[0] = (char)(int)len;
length[1] = '\0';
```

That has implementation-defined characteristics if `char` is a signed type, but in any event, it cannot capture a length greater than the maximum value that can be represented by an `unsigned char`.

The client goes on to do this:

> ```
>     n = write(client_sockfd, length, sizeof length);
> ```

That's not inherently wrong, but it *does* fail to accommodate the possibility of a short write.  Moreover, the server does not interpret this part of the message in a manner consistent with the way it was prepared:

```
        if (readn(connectFD, buffer, 2) == 0) {
          break;
        }
        readLen = (*(short *)&buffer);
```

As it turns out, that combination might happen to work if the server uses a  16-bit, little-endian representation for type `short` (subject to the restriction I already described on representable message length) and an execution character set compatible with the client's, but those are not safe assumptions for network software in general.

In part, you seem to be missing an important point about `read()` and `write()` and `char` pointers: a `char *` can be used to read the representation of an object of any type, so you do not need to move your data into a `char` array in order to send or receive it.

Overall, this would be a more appropriate approach:

```
// Client:
uint16_t len = strlen(buf);                // risk: buf may be too long
uint16_t len_n = htons(len);
int n = writen(client_sockfd, &len_n, 2);  // a write() analog of readn()
// ... handle possible error ...
```

---

```
// Sever:
uint16_t len_n;
int n = readn(connectFD, &len_n, 2);
// ... possible handle error ...
uint16_t readLen = ntohs(len_n);
```

Note that there is no need to copy the length into a separate `char` array to send it, nor to receive it into a `char` array.  On the other hand, note also the use of a specified-size data type (`uint16_t`) on both sides, and the use of `htons()` and `ntohs()` to ensure that the client and server interpret the bytes of the data the same way.  Furthermore, note the use of a write analog of `readn()` to send the data, which otherwise could be sent incompletely.

By the same token the client and server should both use the (hypothetical) `writen()` function to send the text of the message, and just like the server, the client should use `readn()` to read it.  Failing to account for the possibility of short reads and writes is a significant flaw, especially in a protocol such as yours whose message boundaries are not easily distinguishable from data.  An unnoticed short read or write will cause your client and server to fall out of sync, with no easy way to recover.

Comment: Yes - I don't like those simple 'length followed by data' protocols with no other checks, one byte from disaster all the time:(

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It is important to match endian at both sides.

however, i still have a question. First, As far as i know, since data can be fragmented in TCP, it should be able to distinguished boundaries of packets. So I implemented 'readn()'
I know it is not good protocol.. but, why there is possibility of failing to read short data? i don't understand it yet. And then how to deal with fragmentation?

Comment: @Gwanghun, you misunderstand me.  The risk is not of failing to read short data. It is of *successfully* reading (or writing) *less* data than was requested, whether because of fragmentation across packet boundaries, or for any other reason.  If you require reading or writing a specific number of bytes via `read()` or `write()` -- and your protocol does depend on this -- then you must be prepared to do it over multiple `read()` or `write()` calls.  This is exactly what `readn()` does (good on you!), but you need to use it consistently, and to write and use an analogous `writen()` function.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the problems already noticed by @JohnBollinger, you only use a listen window of 1 in server.c when all your forked client processes try to connect at the same time. It caused plenty of `connect : conn reset by peer` errors in my tests. I had to use a window greater than 64 on my FreeBSD (no errors at 256) to get rid of them :

```
if (listen(listenFD, 256) < 0) {
  perror("listen() error\n");
  exit(0);
}
```

Comment: Thanks.. :) I did not know the proper value and I thought there would be no problem with connection even if the queue size was small